# The difference between 'watershed' and 'landmark'

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, ambiguity

Can someone explain to me the difference in the usage of such words as 'watershed' and 'landmark'? I know they both also mean 'a turning point in life'. But is there a difference in their connotations?
Thank you for your feedback in advance!

Answer (score 9):

*Watershed*, used metaphorically, **always** implies a division, separation between two items, just like in its literal sense it stands for the separation between the area from which waters flow to one ocean, sea or river and the area from which they flow to another ocean, sea or river. *Landmark*, on the other hand, stands for anything noteworthy, memorable, that is suitable to use as a reference point. Such reference points **may** mark a division between two items, but they don't always do; that is not a part of the meaning of *landmark*. Eiffel Tower, for example, is a landmark, in the literal sense, but it does not divide Paris into two parts in any significant way. Consequently, if one uses *landmark* metaphorically for an event in somebody's life, it only means that the event is noteworthy, memorable, suitable to use as a reference point. Although turning points usually serve as landmarks in that metaphorical sense, calling something a landmark does not mean that it is a turning point.

Answer (score 2):

"Watershed" implies an event which changes the way things are understood. "Landmark" can be any event or object which marks a division, in time, space, or possibly thought processes.

There is some overlap in the concepts, but "watershed" tends to refer to an "epiphany" (to borrow James Joyce's definition) or a "revelation" -- a relatively sudden recognition that changes ones views of themselves and/or their social conditions.

And "landmark" can refer to an unrelated event -- eg, the turning of the century may be regarded as a "landmark", even though the fact that the century "turned" may not have been a causative factor.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment now deleted FumbleFingers answered:

> [LANDMARK OR WATERSHED.](https://essays.ssrc.org/10yearsafter911/911-landmark-or-watershed/) They're just two different metaphoric usages - one for something that ***stands out, and can be seen from a distance / across the years***, the other identifying a point in space / time when ***the "direction of events" fundamentally changes***. Those distinctions arise quite naturally from the ***literal*** meanings of the two terms.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment now deleted Edwin Ashforth answered:

> Though there is an overlap in meaning, 'landmark' primarily means 'important point / stage in a process / "journey" ' in the metaphorical sense. There need be no Emmaus, life-changing  moment.